# BindableBase: Binding to nested property does not call setter

Tags: mvvm, binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have got the following Models:

```
public class Car : BindableBase
{
    private string _model;
    private string _wheels;

    public string Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _model, value); }
    }

    public string Wheels
    {
        get { return _wheels; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _wheels, value); }
    }
}

public class Customer : BindableBase
{
    private Car _car;

    public Car Car
    {
        get { return _car; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _car, value); }
    }
}
```

And the binding looks like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <viewModels:CustomerViewModelLocator x:Key="PageViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding ViewModel.Car.Model, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource PageViewModel}}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding ViewModel.Car.Wheels, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource PageViewModel}}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I am using the ViewModelLocator pattern for my design time views and it looks good. But at runtime I don´t hit the setters of the models.

What am I doing wrong?

Trivial types within the Customer model would be set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would happen if Car is null. Try setting _car = new Car() in Customer.

Comment: Sometimes... I feel like... ?("$§?)=(%$§(?´($=§!"/&/)="§&$/&%/()&§"($/=?&(=. Thanks!